# Get certain property of a QLineEdit via eventFilter to clipboard

Tags: c++, qt, events, clipboard, qlineedit

I'm attempting to create a `QLineEdit` element whose text will be automatically copied to the clipboard when clicked.

I've created the following `eventFilter` to capture the click event and installed it on the applicable elements:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        qDebug("TEST");
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

What would be the best way from here to gather the data I need from the object to pass to the clipboard function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`QClipboard`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qclipboard.html) class. You can get your application's clipboard using [`qApp->clipboard()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#clipboard) and then set the text from the `QLineEdit`:

```
bool MainWindow::eventFilter(QObject *watched, QEvent *event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::MouseButtonPress)
    {
        auto watched_as_lineEdit = qobject_cast<QLineEdit*>(watched);
        if (watched_as_lineEdit != nullptr) {
            qApp->clipboard()->setText(watched_as_lineEdit->text());
            return true;
        }
    }

    return QMainWindow::eventFilter(watched, event); // change for actual parent class if different from QMainWindow
}
```

Comment: Adapted to global clipboard, works like a charm, thanks!

Comment: Welcome! BTW, I edited the answer just a few minutes ago to fix some bugs on it, sorry about that